# Zimbra contacts synchronization CardDAV (CardBook)

Tags: zimbra, calendar, contacts

has anymbody experience with configuration for synchronization contacts between Zimbra Community Edition and multiple devices with multiple clients MS Outlook/Thunderbird/FossaMail/K9?

Is needed some plugins/zimlets for Zimbra? Or Third-Party software?
I tried Zimbra Connector for MS Outlook, but it doesnt work and it seems, that only works with Non-Community edition.

Anybody tried Z-Push, Zindus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figure it out. The problem in CardBook plugin with validation while adding addressbook was that I used self-signed ceritifcate. So **you have to add server certificate exception in mail client (in my case Thunderbird) manually.** Then validation process is working. And now you have read/write access to your contacts in Zimbra.

FYI: if you use port for example port 8443, then your url is: **https://zimbra.domain.tld:8443/dav/user@domain.tld/NameOfYourContactFolder**

Answer (score 1):

You will need some plugins or use software that is compatible with industry standards as caldav and carddav. I have sucessfully synchronized with Evolution and Thunderbird Lightning with Zimbra using IMAP for e-mail, caldav for the calendar and cardav and ldap for the address books. For thunderbird you'll need some plugins to make it work. The basic key is to know the URL wich is: https://zimbra.server/dav/

I've bought the Caldav sync app ( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dmfs.caldav.lib )for my android phone and still use that because ActiveSync doesn't support multiple calendars.

We did move to the Network Edition bacause of the Outlook connector, ActiveSync and the supurior backup implementation. You can see some examples on how to use ActiveSync on your iPhone on https://www.mailcasa.eu/zimbra-kennisbank-synchronisatie/124-zimbra-instellen-op-een-iphone

Comment: Calendar works fine, but i have trouble with contacts(CardDAV) now.
What exactly plugin do you use for CardDAV in Thunderbird, I tried Cardbook and it fails 
When I use address for connection **"https://server.domain.tld/dav/firstname.lastname@domain.tld/Contacts"**
It fails with some validation

Comment: logs:
2016.04.21 08:57:45:352 : Validation module : Validating without discovery request on https://server.domain.tld/dav/firstname.lastname@domain.tld/Contacts/ ...
2016.04.21 08:57:45:391 : Validation module : Synchronization failed (step : validateWithoutDiscovery, url : https://server.domain.tld/dav/firstname.lastname@domain.tld/Contacts/, status : 0)

When i use plugin CardDav browser, it only shows some information about Insecure Issued Certificate - I use self-signed certificate in Zimbra (last ver.)

Comment: The cardbook plugin does work. It looks a bit the Validation module hangs, but it does not report errors or failed. Maybe you can look in your /opt/zimbra/log/mailbox.log to see if there are any errors noted there.

Comment: no error ebout CardDAV validation attepmts there

Comment: You can allways try to mount the dav directly with your filemanager. I know that the linux nautilus filemanager can connect to davs://zimbra.server/dav/micha@kovoks.nl/

Comment: Yes, Its working to mount dav directly in Caja (alternative to Nautilus) in Ubuntu 16. But still no chance to arrange it in CardBook, CardBook doesnt accept url with davs:// and dav://
By default I use **port 8443** to access zimbra. 
I tried many combinations of url. Address with http:// / https:// with and without port, login name in address etc. With and withount folder path to contact folder. But still cant pass tru Validation process in CardBook plugin in Thunderbird. But thank you Micha K. for tips.
**Any more ideas please?**